# Android SwipeRefreshLayout webview unable to scroll down

Tags: android

I am new to the android. Currently I want to use the SwipeRefreshLayout with webview but I am unable to scroll down in my webview, everytime I scroll down will trigger the SwipeRefreshLayout event. Any suggestion and step I can avoid this ?Below is sample coding i refer to.

Here is my current layout:

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/swipe">


    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And here is my activity

```
package com.example.web3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private WebView webView;
        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //SwipeRefresh
            swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe_contain);
            swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {

                    webView.loadUrl(webView.getUrl());
                }
            });
            swipeRefresh.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_light, 
                                                 android.R.color.holo_red_light, 
                                                 android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
                                                 android.R.color.holo_green_light);

            webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_show);

            webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.28/sample/index.html");

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

            webView.requestFocus(); 

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onScrollChanged() {
                     if (webView.getScrollY() == 0) {
                         swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
                      } else {
                          swipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
                      }
                  }
                });



            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    if(newProgress == 100){

                        swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    }else if(!swipeRefresh.isRefreshing()){
                        swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);

                    }
                }
            });
        }



}
```

Comment: put your layout here

Comment: Hi, @H.Kai Do you find any working solution for this, I have done Lot of R&D but not find any fix for it..

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            if (webView.getScrollY() == 0) {
                swipeToRefresh.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                swipeToRefresh.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i already added to the code but still getting refresh by the SwipeRefreshLayout . i already added my code , is that the way i added were wrong ?

Comment: ok. just try to implement touchlistener too on webview and on action down **swipeToRefresh.setEnabled(false);** and on action up **swipeToRefresh.setEnabled(true);**

Comment: Hi Rahul, this code is not working, SwipeRefreshLayout always overlap Webview scroll event.